# Synchronize several sqlite databases to one mysql database

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I want to synchronize my android sqlite database with an external mysql database. The problem is that I have more than one android client and I want to have the information updated in mysql database. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks
PD: All databases has the same schema but clients don't have the same info

Answer (score 0):

Write a web service (eg. methods could be pushChanges, getChanges) which would help keeping both the databases in sync. Suppose you are using Android Client 1, whenever you save something in SQLite, call web service to push these changes to MySql. Call getChanges to get any other changes in MySql which would have been done by some other client, write them to your SQLite.